# Hibernate: how do I retrieve my entities from a ScrollableResults?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, orm

I do a query that returns a list of entities. How can I retrieve the entities from a `ScrollableResults`:

```
 Session s  = ....;
 Query q = s.createQuery("....") # returns 100000s rows
 ScrollableResults sr = q.scroll();
 sr.scroll(45999); # just a number
 Employee employee = ???
```

How do I get an employee in the last line of code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the `get(0)` method, or `get()[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to API: [ScrollableResults](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html)

`get()` returns the entire current row, `get(index)` returns object at `index` position without initializing the rest of them. There are also a bunch of convenience getXXX() methods that cast result to given type.

Comment: This post would be more useful if you provided an example. For instance, what would the "entire current row" look like if you were getting Customers? If Customer has two fields, name and ID, I would expect get[0] to be the name and get[1] to be the ID. But it isn't, get[0] is the Customer from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

> I do a query that returns a list of entities. How can I retrieve the entities from a ScrollableResults... How do I get an employee.

Just to improve the other answers, the `ScrollableResults` does the entity conversion for you although this isn't immediately clear from the Javadocs.

As @Bozho says, calling `sr.get()` will return the entity at the current location, but wrapped in an array.  In looking at the code for `ScrollableResultsImpl` the current row's result is set with:

```
    if ( result != null && result.getClass().isArray() ) {
        currentRow = (Object[]) result;
    } else {
        currentRow = new Object[] { result };
    }
```

So `ScrollableResults.get()` always returns an array of results and if your entity is *not* an array, it will be at `get()[0]`.

So, with your code you would do something like:

```
while (sr.next()) {
   // get the entity which is the first element in an Object[]
   Employee employee = sr.get()[0];
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve entities the simplest way would be to cast the object to whichever object you want:
E.g:

```
ScrollableResults sr = q.scroll();
while (sr.next()) {
    CustomObject object = (CustomObject) sr.get()[0]; // Now CustomObject will have all the properties mapped
}
```

This works perfect for all the scenarios.